# Junit test case for the below method

Tags: java, junit, applet, class-method

I am still new to JUnit testing. I am writing junit tests for this method:

```
public void LoadApplet(JPanel panel) {
    AppletClass applet = new AppletClass();

    applet.init();
    panel.add(applet,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    applet.start();
}
```

Comment: For testing GUIs you mai use FEST framework (with Cacio)

Comment: Unit testing comes from testing units. Which unit are you testing here? The AppletClass? Or the adding to the panel? Depending on how complex the AppletClass is, this may be much more than a Unit test. If not, all you can do is to check is afterwards, the applet is in the correct place and initialized...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz : I want to test the AppletClass, if the methods _init()_ and _start()_ are called.

Comment: That's a contradiction. Do you want to test `AppletClass` OR do you want to call if the methods are called? If you want to make sure that `LoadApplet` calles the correct methods, then you can refactor it and give it some mocks on which to test that. If you want to make sure the `AppletClas.init()` and `start()` behave correcly, then there is no need to call the `LoadApplet` method for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the unit test this way and it worked:

```
public void TestLoadApplet() {
  AppletClass instance = new AppletClass();

  JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // Creating a empty panel
  instance.LoadApplet(panel);
  assertEquals("java.awt.BorderLayout", panel.getLayout().getClass().getName());
  assertEquals("Applets.AppletClassName", panel.getComponent().getClass().getName());
  }
```